# How to reset storage password in Mule Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have downloaded new version of mule studio, and I am trying to configure it. First I am trying to set network connections. After editing proxy entries, when I click on apply I am presented with "please enter the secure storage password". I have not set any such password.
and I do not see any option of resetting it. Long time ago I had installed some earlier version of mule studio. I did simply delete that directory before reinstalling new one. Could that be a problem. In any case what would be a way out.
Thanks for your help or suggestion on where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be due to the old installation, as the Secure Storage file location is usually some hidden Eclipse settings directory. It is used to store proxy authentication data. See Preferences -> Security -> Secure Storage for the Secure Storage settings, and specifically the Contents tab for Storage location and the Delete button that should delete the previous Secure Storage. A restart might be needed.